# How to change the fill color of an SVG icon referenced by a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, icons

I have a URL that points to an SVG icon, and I want to use this icon in my web application. However, I also need to change the fill color of the icon dynamically based on user input.

What is the best way to achieve this? Do I need to download the SVG file and modify its contents, or is there a way to apply the fill color directly to the referenced icon using CSS or JavaScript?

Any code examples or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
enter image description here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <object id="icon" data="https://################.s3.amazonaws.com/flag.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="icon">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-path" class="icon-path" />
            </svg>
        </object>
    </div>

    <script>
        const iconElement = document.getElementById('icon');
        iconElement.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const svgDocument = iconElement.contentDocument;
            if (svgDocument && svgDocument.length > 0) {
                const svgPaths = svgDocument.querySelectorAll('.icon-path');
                svgPaths.forEach((path) => {
                    path.style.fill = 'red';
                });
            } else {
                console.error('SVG document not found or has a zero length');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

svgDocument is null

Comment: this is  because your SVG is inside an `<object>`, which is also a   protection where any inside elements and can't be acceded (?)

Comment: Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd) I blogged about.